# Regression tree cross validation confusing results

Tags: decision-trees, cross-validation

## Setup

I have implemented regression trees in go: [full repository](https://github.com/robertkotcher/goml2)

Using the full dataset and [cost-complexity pruning](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Cost-Complexity_Pruning), I get the following alphas and corresponding average residual (again, against the full dataset):

```
alpha 0, avg residual 14.134395421607389
alpha 0.12883399209486168, avg residual 14.148010046113317
alpha 0.1653326745718049, avg residual 14.185322598514801
alpha 0.16639262187088283, avg residual 14.294436412237312
.
. <skipped for brevity>
.
alpha 621.0306084614934, avg residual 36.3987567628702  
alpha 739.3793217781949, avg residual 43.51964252487374  
alpha 837.3864710344569, avg residual 61.267903297185946  
alpha 1026.5185269754365, avg residual 84.4195561561656
```

I believe this is correct because smaller alphas penalize larger trees less, so smaller alphas should also have lower average residuals. Since these are results from the training dataset, we run cross validation and get the following best alpha/residual for each fold (typical results):

```
fold 0: alpha 0, error: 911.9933467781559
fold 1: alpha 15.414289473684207, error: 599.9848234221355
fold 2: alpha 7.063954870729459, error: 1168.1684906780179
fold 3: alpha 0.29686925647451967, error: 2082.105952653071
fold 4: alpha 15.08986257309941, error: 2491.851239853936
fold 5: alpha 1.2758108552631582, error: 1543.555675071225
fold 6: alpha 651.0241925560358, error: 2373.5789896637143
fold 7: alpha 2.3170317286271227, error: 1363.5892092966592
fold 8: alpha 1.7122904483430803, error: 1209.2366845834206
fold 9: alpha 59.18484461152882, error: 1927.6639759480731
```

Running cross-validation several times returns average alphas that don't seem to be consistent.

## Question

Could it be possible that cross-validation returns such different results for each fold? I would expect that each fold returns *similar* results, but it also seems like decision trees are particularly volatile during construction, i.e. a small change in the dataset could result in a vastly different tree.

Comment: With a small dataset this might be reasonable.  I would look at the selected trees' maximum depths (if very different, then the data split is likely at fault?), and generate graphs of test-error-vs-alpha for each fold (maybe the test scores are fairly flat, so "best" alpha isn't necessarily clear even for a single fold).

Comment: Maybe also try running an existing implementation on your dataset, preferably fixing the splits in advance.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger, yes this is run on the standard boston housing dataset, and is quite small. Good idea about checking all of the alphas across the folds. The set of alphas seems to vary quite a bit with the entire set, but maybe it'll look different during cross-validation.